# Multiple streams inside single gulp-if calling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-if

In the below code, I do `plugins.if(
  !config.isDevelopmentMode && config.compileBladeTemplates, /* task */)` check twice (**plugins.if** is **gulp-if** package). Can I refactor below code with one check? Not sure that it possible just with **gulp-if**, so it's allowed to use additional plugins.

```
const   gulp = require('gulp'),
        plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// ...
.pipe(plugins.if(
  !config.isDevelopmentMode && config.compileBladeTemplates,
  plugins.replace(
     /<!--\s+@blade\s+namedRoute\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\s*-->\s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)?\s*(<.+href=")(?:.+?)(".*\/?>)/g,
     `$2{{ route('$1') }}$3`
  )
))
.pipe(plugins.if(
  !config.isDevelopmentMode && config.compileBladeTemplates,
  plugins.replace(
     /<!--\s+@blade\s+(yield|include)\s*-->/g,
     ` @$1('$2')`
  )
))
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do I think a lazypipe would work for you.  See [gulp-if with lazypipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if#works-great-with-lazypipe).

```
var replaceChannel = lazypipe()
      plugins.replace(
     /<!--\s+@blade\s+namedRoute\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\s*-->\s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)?\s*(<.+href=")(?:.+?)(".*\/?>)/g,
     `$2{{ route('$1') }}$3`
    )
    plugins.replace(
     /<!--\s+@blade\s+(yield|include)\s*-->/g,
     ` @$1('$2')`
   );
```

and then in your task:

```
.pipe(plugins.if(
  !config.isDevelopmentMode && config.compileBladeTemplates, replaceChannel()))
```